# How to open file with notepad++ in command line. (start notepad++ create new file instead of open current file) (Windows)

Tags: windows, cmd, notepad++

I would like to open file in windows command line like :

```
start notepad++ currentFile
```

Actually those works

```
start notepad++ "C:\Users\user\currentFile"
```

or

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" .gitconfig
```

But I would like to open without specifiy file or notepad directory.
So I have copy Notepad

Thanks

Comment: That's how absolute and relative paths work. You either specify the full path (like you did in  your first example), or make sure that the _current working directory_ is the one where the file is located (e.g. `cd c:\users\user\ & notepad++ currentFile`).

Comment: You can also add a the notepad++ path to the Windows environment `PATH` system variable. Then it would be available from any of those locations.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it by adding an alias for this long command. It seems that you use Git bash on Windows, then it is pretty simple. Below example shows how to add an alias for Git bash and use it:

```
# Add an alias "np" for notepad++
$ echo "alias np=\"/c/'Program Files (x86)'/Notepad++/notepad++.exe\"" >> ~/.bashrc

# Make the newly added alias take effect immediately
$ . ~/.bashrc

# Open a file with notepad++
$ np .gitconfig

# Just open notepad++
$ np
```

And you can find more on [making Git bash on Windows better](https://comprostack.netlify.app/tools/cmd/make-git-bash-on-windows-a-better-terminal/).